# sql server: How to find exact match in all the database objects?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select B.* from sys.sql_modules A
JOIN  SYS.objects B ON A.object_id=B.object_id
WHERE definition LIKE '%Packages%'
```

I want to find all the occurrences of word 'Packages' in all my databse results. I want to only get back results which have this exact match 'Packages' and not other which has this as substring?

Right now i get SPs with 'SPAPacakges' etc which have 'Packages' as substring. I want to remove these.

How do i do that?

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, 
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.Packages', 'OBJECT');
```

This is working for me. But i am not sure whether its perfect. I don't understand its complete meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all occurrences of the word `Packages`, possibly with whitespace before or after it (i.e. the word by itself in isolation), then you can try the following `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE definition LIKE ' Packages' OR
      definition LIKE 'Packages ' OR
      definition LIKE ' Packages ' OR
      definition LIKE 'Packages'
```

Comment: It is not returning any results.

Comment: You should also show us some sample records from your tables.

Comment: My original posted query returns me results with words like 'TC_SoldRSAPackages'. When i modified it like you suggested, its not giving any results. Although i ahve multiple SP's that have words like 'Packages'.

Comment: This is why it is so critical for you to show us what you are trying to match (which you still haven't done).  I had to make an assumption to give you answer.  Show us sample data and your desired outcome.

Comment: Apologies if i didn't made myself clear. But i mentioned in first line-I want to find all the occurrences of word 'Packages' in all my databse results.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove wildcards `%` from `'Packages'` and you could add `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to avoid issues with whitespaces, in following:

```
select B.* from sys.sql_modules A
JOIN  SYS.objects B ON A.object_id=B.object_id
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(definition)) LIKE 'Packages'
```

Comment: It is not returning any results.